# Browse Button for folder not files

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am adding a browse button on an Access 2010 form; it will only allow me to attach files, not folders. Here is the code:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Private Declare Function GetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias _
"GetOpenFileNameA" (pOpenfilename As OPENFILENAME) As Long

Private Type OPENFILENAME
    lStructSize As Long
    hwndOwner As Long
    hInstance As Long
    lpstrFilter As String
    lpstrCustomFilter As String
    nMaxCustFilter As Long
    nFilterIndex As Long
    lpstrFile As String
    nMaxFile As Long
    lpstrFileTitle As String
    nMaxFileTitle As Long
    lpstrInitialDir As String
    lpstrTitle As String
    flags As Long
    nFileOffset As Integer
    nFileExtension As Integer
    lpstrDefExt As String
    lCustData As Long
    lpfnHook As Long
    lpTemplateName As String
End Type

Function LaunchCD(strform As Form) As String
    Dim OpenFile As OPENFILENAME
    Dim lReturn As Long
    Dim sFilter As String
    OpenFile.lStructSize = Len(OpenFile)
    OpenFile.hwndOwner = strform.Hwnd
    sFilter = "All Files (*.*)" & Chr(0) & "*.*" & Chr(0) & _
      "JPEG Files (*.JPG)" & Chr(0) & "*.JPG" & Chr(0)
    OpenFile.lpstrFilter = sFilter
    OpenFile.nFilterIndex = 1
    OpenFile.lpstrFile = String(257, 0)
    OpenFile.nMaxFile = Len(OpenFile.lpstrFile) - 1
    OpenFile.lpstrFileTitle = OpenFile.lpstrFile
    OpenFile.nMaxFileTitle = OpenFile.nMaxFile
    OpenFile.lpstrInitialDir = "C:\"
    OpenFile.lpstrTitle = "Select a file using the Common Dialog DLL"
    OpenFile.flags = 0
    lReturn = GetOpenFileName(OpenFile)
        If lReturn = 0 Then
            MsgBox "A file was not selected!", vbInformation, _
              "Select a file using the Common Dialog DLL"
         Else
            LaunchCD = Trim(Left(OpenFile.lpstrFile, InStr(1, OpenFile.lpstrFile, vbNullChar) - 1))
         End If
End Function
```

Comment: I edited the title of your question to remove the "Access" tag  - the answer to [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) is "no"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the documentation for [GetOpenFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> To display a dialog box that allows the user to select a directory [folder]
>   instead of a file, call the
>   [SHBrowseForFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
>   function.